# How to solve this error without "multiDexEnabled true"

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --output D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\1f\main D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_57afc2c35a0df73a1f14ad7a267d6ebbe51cb181.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\okio-1.13.0_434134a57ee3fb4889ccc0c8323d5df8dcc2fea6.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_760c65cdc25edbaa14f157f3f6ba8f96a5f99df9.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_c4150f8cb9fdaecc149ab600ab3739e4543f2fd8.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_23a28045762e0221c83adc3d4696a6e88e353b95.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_7cbc7977d857cdcfd7082c2d1cfc6ed21c104844.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-27.1.0_f5701f86f53abedc181bf6a95496da8be54c0775.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-25.0.1_fd141cab64fa26e55915ee1f61299552851fbac7.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_e070c894fed318f6cc49bad367353adfeb231434.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_cf5be631c0710dac59d882f5dd5d036f99a3efa6.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\common-1.1.0_34eec8f89b838b6b466c51dc150163df502cc2fd.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\library-2.4.0_16c20551d1515298e4f820dbb2437cde217a49b7.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_830a18c57e2fa139be984db8e062e776f4f2129a.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_b67e5aceef7d1a77fb7403eee9eb5e05cbd97e0a.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_d5e0da78314cb9c5e689ee1f04f42aae57f61c09.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\converter-gson-2.3.0_62d527d56a820800b3bc65db406fbd298eb1c807.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_1f086e1ad9374bea311d88de190c2ea7a60af61f.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\glide-3.7.0_dc2cedaf25df8c5e199ffaaa969663929f0fc4fc.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_527a4671a6aed3b60fb76f00df697e9f156d7188.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_55321007cd2d081e5a260a8c6dd32948cf9cbcd8.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_9731ecc8adddbfa10c33fd1ebed07386f485420f.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_026ddaa7f2009dd3b4bbbce3905628e91e6bf2bd.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_2ba81573f53bb07daf9d805fc261f172a96c3677.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_1bf5a4c00f65b72bc4859b2d5821f73bbfa74442.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_6e85be5a5d04e5d4e42f8a57d151830437d3734d.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\retrofit-2.3.0_b38cd094d04b0aecf686dec3655bfce5ccfbdb81.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_4e161fe630ed403a047a0c37a3e80e4ff57dd586.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\gson-2.8.0_4f4ff1cf61174743e4574eab8dc93d00100afda8.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_5e3ffa42e4062fa505d4d230ff57ef2bb9dd6c88.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_9f00634473f3639b2cda67dd83e860a75657b582.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_ebcd677f747e73d6b28139d6267cca7936108fc3.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\debug_503b6445f49702b773aa097a8dd02b65dcdc65f0.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\logging-interceptor-3.3.1_5ba3d9c2609b038ccff64586daa6f9dbce85a6a2.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_db77575bc4e7021e9bce10c14b75e6bf1a397ff4.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi_f636ad954a363fa03746e08d531541fd84b7895f.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_5b7f4fa39cf8e76dcb214d1d57f4b5e3a1fe87b1.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\common-1.1.0_a0c175c60319cc8661e4f434c5fccdd4b00a096e.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_97f0728eeba8e1c1b1fbeb982637bed57fd86a88.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\butterknife-7.0.1_b166c6acd2be2eb9315008c1cf987d5f0c122f6f.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_e4fbcddc542076b3864a1b46fa401020e75dc03e.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_81106fc2f8504b5eb0ff7ce9c095b12eab4ee75a.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_b9425fa7e7016264df5f98e89ba648af09495ec7.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_3e1f5bfdc2a8f2683f86a5c6cb7fb3c39603db7f.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\constraint-layout-solver-1.0.2_7746369fa27cceb525736b4267461e18a05a6d43.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_258f0edce677a1dbdbec2cb67ba577640c9001b4.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_e228dad667cec56ab67b41e9214c5afae138ceac.jar D:\PTMIP\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\okhttp-3.8.0_3840c3c4709b44feecbe1313170b0186f98ebea1.jar}

Project gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ptmip"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //View Init
    //DateTime Picker
    //Edittext
    //Image loader
    //Retrofit
    //youtube player
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    //firebase notification


    //PDF Library

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.2.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: If you already know multidex is the problem then just enable it . What's the point here ??

Comment: why you don't want to enable multidex?? any conflict or other issue?

Comment: You need to post your build gradle to find out

Comment: but why require multidex is enable  in my project?

Comment: Enabling multidex is something very common in 'big' apps.. If you want to avoid it, you can start by using less dependencies...

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1.class